# Changing the value of a variable using the do_action_ref_array hook - pass by reference

Tags: wordpress, pass-by-reference, contact-form-7

I am stuck and I can't find any helpful documentation on how to solve my problem. The problem is related to an action hook in the contact form 7 code:

```
    private function before_send_mail() {
    $abort = false;

    do_action_ref_array( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', array(
        $this->contact_form,
        &$abort,
        $this,
    ) );

    return ! $abort;
}
```

Now what I want is to use the `do_action_ref_array` hook to change the value of `$abort` from `false` to `true`. I have tried many things including the following:

```
function abort_send(&$cf7array) {
$cf7array[1] = true;
}
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'abort_send' );
```

I know that I should be able to change the value of `&$abort`inside of the `abort_send function` (pass by reference). But I can't exactly figure out how.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out how to do it. The trick is that `do_action_ref_array` passes its argument not as an array but instead passes each value of the array as an individual argument. But it doesn't stop there... Apparently `add_action` only accepts 1 argument by default. In other words, in order to pass all the individual arguments part of the array in `do_action_ref_array` this default value needs to be changed. The final result that ended up working for me is:

```
function abort_send($arg1, &$abort, $arg3 ) {
    $abort = true;
}
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'abort_send', 10, 999 );
```

Here 10 has to do with the order of execution of the added action hook and 999 is the number of accepted arguments (again, which is 1 by default).

I hope that this will help others with the same problem. If something in my explanation is unclear please let me know and I will try to help out!